# ArrowInvalid: Could not convert ... with type DataFrame: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type

Tags: pandas, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

Using IForest library implementing a function for detection outliers using the following code:

```
import pyspark.pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from alibi_detect.od import IForest

# **************** Modelo IForest ******************************************
# IForest rta - Outlier ---> 1, Not-Outlier ----> 0

od = IForest(
    threshold=0.,
    n_estimators=5
)

def mode(lm):
    freqs = groupby(Counter(lm).most_common(), lambda x:x[1])
    m=[val for val,count in next(freqs)[1]]
    if len(m)>1:
        m=np.median(lm)
    else:
        m=float(m[0])
    return m

def disper(x):
    x_pred = x[['precio_local', 'precio_contenido']]
    insumo_std = x_pred.std().to_frame().T
    mod = mode(x_pred['precio_local'])
    x_send2 = pd.DataFrame( 
        index=x_pred.index,
        columns=['Std_precio','Std_prec_cont','cant_muestras','Moda_precio_local','IsFo']
    )
    x_send2.loc[:,'Std_precio'] = insumo_std.loc[0,'precio_local']
    x_send2.loc[:,'Std_prec_cont'] = insumo_std.loc[0,'precio_local']
    x_send2.loc[:,'Moda_precio_local'] = mod
    mod_cont = mode(x_pred['precio_contenido'])
    x_send2.loc[:,'Moda_precio_contenido_std'] = mod_cont
    ctn = x_pred.shape[0]
    x_send2.loc[:,'cant_muestras'] = ctn    
    if x_pred.shape[0]>3:
      od.fit(x_pred)
      preds = od.predict(
          x_pred,
          return_instance_score=True
      )
      
      x_preds = preds['data']['is_outlier']
      #x_send2.loc[:,'IsFo']=x_preds
      pd.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)
      x_send2.loc[:,'IsFo']= pd.Series(x_preds, index=x_pred.index)
      #x_send2.insert(x_pred.index, 'IsFo', x_preds)
    else:
        x_send2.loc[:,'IsFo'] = 0
    print(type(x_send2))
    print(x_send2)
    return x_send2

insumo_all_pd = insumo_all.to_pandas_on_spark()
```

I get the error:

```
    ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1939548125702628> in <module>
----> 1 df_result = insumo_all_pd.groupby(by=['categoria','marca','submarca','barcode','contenido_std','unidad_std']).apply(disper)
      2 display(df_result)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/usage_logging/__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    192             start = time.perf_counter()
    193             try:
--> 194                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    195                 logger.log_success(
    196                     class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1200             else:
   1201                 pser_or_pdf = grouped.apply(pandas_apply, *args, **kwargs)
-> 1202             psser_or_psdf = ps.from_pandas(pser_or_pdf)
   1203 
   1204             if len(pdf) <= limit:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/usage_logging/__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    187         if hasattr(_local, "logging") and _local.logging:
    188             # no need to log since this should be internal call.
--> 189             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    190         _local.logging = True
    191         try:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/namespace.py in from_pandas(pobj)
    143     """
    144     if isinstance(pobj, pd.Series):
--> 145         return Series(pobj)
    146     elif isinstance(pobj, pd.DataFrame):
    147         return DataFrame(pobj)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/usage_logging/__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    187         if hasattr(_local, "logging") and _local.logging:
    188             # no need to log since this should be internal call.
--> 189             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    190         _local.logging = True
    191         try:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    424                     data=data, index=index, dtype=dtype, name=name, copy=copy, fastpath=fastpath
    425                 )
--> 426             internal = InternalFrame.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(s))
    427             if s.name is None:
    428                 internal = internal.copy(column_labels=[None])

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/internal.py in from_pandas(pdf)
   1458             data_columns,
   1459             data_fields,
-> 1460         ) = InternalFrame.prepare_pandas_frame(pdf)
   1461 
   1462         schema = StructType([field.struct_field for field in index_fields + data_fields])

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/internal.py in prepare_pandas_frame(pdf, retain_index)
   1531 
   1532         for col, dtype in zip(reset_index.columns, reset_index.dtypes):
-> 1533             spark_type = infer_pd_series_spark_type(reset_index[col], dtype)
   1534             reset_index[col] = DataTypeOps(dtype, spark_type).prepare(reset_index[col])
   1535 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/typedef/typehints.py in infer_pd_series_spark_type(pser, dtype)
    327             return pser.iloc[0].__UDT__
    328         else:
--> 329             return from_arrow_type(pa.Array.from_pandas(pser).type)
    330     elif isinstance(dtype, CategoricalDtype):
    331         if isinstance(pser.dtype, CategoricalDtype):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: Could not convert      Std_precio  Std_prec_cont  cant_muestras  Moda_precio_local  IsFo  Moda_precio_contenido_std
107         0.0            0.0              3                1.0     0                   1.666667
252         0.0            0.0              3                1.0     0                   1.666667
396         0.0            0.0              3                1.0     0                   1.666667 with type DataFrame: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type
```

The error encountered by using:

```
df_result = insumo_all_pd.groupby(by=['categoria','marca','submarca','barcode','contenido_std','unidad_std']).apply(disper)
```

The schema of dataframe insumo_all_pd is:

```
fecha_ola            datetime64[ns]
pais                         object
categoria                    object
marca                        object
submarca                     object
contenido_std               float64
unidad_std                   object
barcode                      object
precio_local                float64
cantidad                    float64
descripcion                  object
id_ticket                    object
id_item                      object
id_pdv                       object
fecha_transaccion    datetime64[ns]
id_ref                      float64
precio_contenido            float64
dtype: object
```

It is not clear to me what is causing the error but it seems that the data types are being inferred incorrectly.
I have tried to convert the data types resulting from the `"disper"` function to float but it gives the same error.

I appreciate any help or guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Jupyter, apparently, has changed some of the pandas related libraries. The solution's upgrading to Jupyter 5.

Comment: Actually I am using databricks notebooks on Azure.